# Get PDF MD5 Hash in Delphi

Tags: delphi, pdf, hash, couchdb, md5

I am using Delphi to generate hash MD5 from pdf file.
I would like to generate the same hash as CouchDB attachment hash,
but I get different result.

My function to generate Hash:

```
function TPliki.generujHashMD5(zawartoscPliku: TMemoryStream): string;
var
  tekstPliku: string;

begin
  setString(tekstPliku, PAnsiChar(zawartoscPliku.Memory), zawartoscPliku.Size);
  result := THashMD5.GetHashString(tekstPliku);
end;
```

1. Before function I load file to TMemoryStream using TMemoryStream.LoadFromFile(path)
2. Call this function TPliki.GenerujHashMD5(fileContent): string;
3. In this function I generate Hash and return string with result.
   My hash is different when I decode from Base64 CouchDB Hash.

Settings in CouchDB for Attachments:

```
compressible_types: text/*, application/javascript, application/json, application/xml
compression_level: 0
```

Comment: First you have to check what kind of hash algorithm is used by couch db

Comment: Are you certain that `zawartoscPliku.Memory` will never contain a NULL character? That could lead to premature termination when casting to PAnsiChar.

Comment: I am generating PDF file, then I hash its content. I assume it must have at least one character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem with your code is that you are converting content of PDF file - binary data to Unicode string and with that you are altering its content. And that changes your hash value.

You should be using `THashMD5` in different way, and supply binary data directly without converting it to string.

```
function TPliki.generujHashMD5(zawartoscPliku: TMemoryStream): string;
var
  hash: THashMD5;
begin
  hash := THashMD5.Create;
  hash.Update(zawartoscPliku.Memory, zawartoscPliku.Size);
  result := hash.HashAsString;
end;
```

Comment: I have a question - I can see in the documentation (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Hash.THashMD5), THashMD5 is a static record, but why I need to call Create() ? There should not be memory Leak ? Or maybe use Rest() for clear content before Update() ?

Comment: I don't have XE8 so I cannot check source code, but if Delphi libraries provide `Create` for record that means that it requires some additional initialization (besides pure memory allocation). And even if it does not have it at the moment, it is possible that in future such initialization will be needed. If `Create` is part of public API then using it is playing safe inside your code. Or in another words it does not cost you to use it, and it may cost you if you don't use it.